# How to use ngClass on many elements with variable in ts

Tags: angular, ng-class, angular12

I have a variable in my ts file that toggles when a button is clicked:

```
expanded: boolean = false;

  expandStuff() {
    this.expanded = !this.expanded;
    }
```

I have a few divs that I want this toggle to affect and change the class of the div. So I thought I could use ngClass:

```
[ngClass]="{'max-stuff' : expanded}"
```

I added only this to the divs I want to be affected. But I have been unable to get it to work. Literally nothing happens. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to add something else? Is my syntax incorrect?

Comment: Looks okay with the code. Anyway, can you create a Minimal Reproducible Example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)? So we can know the structure of your code and the root cause.

Comment: As Yong stated, this should work fine. Probably something else going on. Either create a stackblitz or post more surrounding code.

Comment: I discovered it won't work if I have a style the class would affect set inline already. makes sense really :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a root component, have you imported **BrowserModule**?

If it's a child component, have you imported **CommonModule**?

As an example

```
import {BrowserModule} from "@angular/platform-browser"

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule]
})
export class SomeModule {}
```